# How to use existing javascript codes in react components

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, reactjs

I am new to React Js. I have some normal javascript codes for frequently used calculations and etc and it has lots of javascript codes.

Now i am moving to React Components and like to use same codes which i have written in plain javascript in my react components instead of re-writing everything.

Kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Think of creating a util/ or lib/ folder on the root of your project. You can export those functions etc and use anywhere as you would normally.

There is nothing related to react, except you shoudn t try to update the dom via plain JS. Shortly, let react do what it does, elsewhere use your own util, lib helpers without issues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. @FurkanO. What should i do if plain JS updates the dom?